# Google Sheets Custom Function - use function input as condition in IF statement

Tags: javascript, google-sheets

I am trying to create a custom function in google sheets. As part of the function I would like to use the input to select from list of return options.

I.E. in one the cells I would like to write **=IfTest(PB)** and have it return **PB** or **=IfTest(assets)** and have it return **assets**. Regardless of my inputs, it only returns PB.

```
function iftest(x) {

if (x = 'PB') {
 return 'PB';

} else if (x = 'assets') {
  return 'assets';

} else {}
}
```

Comment: This code lack a lot of knowledge about basic programming. I would recommend you to follow some [javascript guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide) to learn about variables, types and all the basic stuff.

Comment: thanks, I'll check that out. this is my first foray into javascript

Answer (score 0):

If PB is the string you are looking for then it needs '' or "" around it. For example:

```
function customFunction(x) {

  var assets = 'something';
  if (x == 'PB') {
    return 'PB';
    
  } else if (x == assets) {
  
    return assets;
    
  } else {
  
  return '';
  
  }
  
}
```

Comment: Changing the conditional to == instead of = solved the problem. Thank you. Part of the issue was that in the cell, I had to write the x as a string with quotes. i.e. IfTest("PB")